# Getting error while using readImageBlob() with inline SVG

Tags: php, laravel, imagemagick

I am using the Imagick library to convert the inline SVG into the PNG file. I am using this library with Laravel. firstly I have initialized the instance of Imagick.`$magick = new \Imagick();`. After that when I have passed the inline SVG variable (that contains the SVG data) into the `readImageBlob($svg)` it's throwing the error "**`no decode delegate for this image format` ' @ error/blob.c/BlobToImage/458`**".

Answer (score 1):

SVG is just xml, and it's possible ImageMagick can't identify which image-format the XML represents. IF this is the case, it would fallback on the filename extension; which, you omitted by reading as a blob. Try defining the format before reading.

```php
$magick = new \Imagick();
$magick->setFormat('SVG');
$magick->readImageBlob($svg);
```

Comment: can you please tell me how can I define format before reading?